# Auth0 returning 401 unauthorized when requesting new auth token

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, axios, auth0

I am trying to request an authorization token through auth0 using an M2M application with the code:

```
var axios = require("axios").default;

var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://chaptify.us.auth0.com/oauth/token',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    data: {
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        client_id: 'KbFUk08Qq24VA03i1mVAkLc3uPKc6V79',
        client_secret: process.env.AUTH0_M2M_CLIENT_SECRET,
        audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE
    }
};

axios.request(options).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

which is pulled straight from auth0's website. but every time I've gotten a 401 error so far I've tried

1. using different M2M applications
2. making sure all the M2M applications are authorized and trying again
3. checking the Token Endpoint Authentication Method is set to None
4. checking all the fields are correct
5. googling to see if I can find absolutely anything to help
6. pasting in the values directly
7. unauthorizing the M2M shutting down the application, waiting a while then starting it up again, nothing

Comment: what does the `console.error(error)` print?

Comment: Also that content type seems suspect -- I think it requires `application/json` -- https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#parameters

Comment: @Joe weirdly enough changing the type to `application/json` worked

Comment: Yay accurate documentation!